# How to change the data from CSV to Json format

Tags: java, rest, cucumber

I have a export to csv option, which exports the data and displays the result as
Student ID,Due Date,Enrollment ID,Joining Date,Amount,Currency
1,23-10-2021,346,23-12-2021,23000,RS
2,23-10-2021,347,23-12-2021,23000,RS
3,23-10-2021,348,23-12-2021,23000,RS
4,23-10-2021,349,23-12-2021,23000,RS
5,23-10-2021,340,23-12-2021,23000,RS
6,23-10-2021,341,23-12-2021,23000,RS

I want this to be converted to JSON format. I am working on Automation using Cucumber, selenium JAva and restassured framework

Comment: See https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-convert-csv-to-json-in-java

Comment: WHY do you want it as JSON?

Comment: I have another JSON, i need to compare the csv details with JSON response.. i have code for comparision of two JSONs